# Format inline CSS with Python

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file with following code inside:

```
<...some tags...>
<textarea id="123" attributeX="4" attributeY="5" style="width:159px; height:50px; other styles;">
<textarea id="456" attributeX="4" attributeY="5" style="width:135px; height:50px; other styles;">
<textarea id="789" attributeX="4" attributeY="5" style="width:177px; height:50px; other styles;">
<...some other tags...>
```

I want to change the width of all textareas to 200px by the use of Python 2.0.
My first idea was to use BeautifulSoup and I found this code snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cssutils import parseStyle

html = '<td style="font-size: .8em; font-family: monospace; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);"></td>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
style = parseStyle(soup.td['style'])
style['background-color'] = 'red'
soup.td['style'] = style.cssText
print(soup.td)
```

Unfortunately, this only changes the style of **one** tag.
I want to change **all** textarea tags

I tried the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cssutils import parseStyle

soup = BeautifulSoup(sHTML,'html.parser')
for txt in soupfindAll('textarea'):
   style = parseStyle(text.textarea['style'])
   style['width'] = '200px'
   txt.textarea['style'] = style.cssText
```

This generates a "NoneType object is not subscriptable" error on the line "style = ..."

Does anyone have an idea how I can perform the required formatting?

Thanks

Comment: If possible, replace all of the inline styles with an external stylesheet, then you won't have to resort to an HTML parser just to change a width property. As for your code, where might `soupfindAll` be defined? Is this really `soup.findAll`? (prefer `soup.find_all`). Also, prefer `lxml` to `html.parser`. `txt` is different than `text`; maybe you have a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cssutils import parseStyle

with open('input.html') as f_html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_html, 'html.parser')
    
for textarea in soup.find_all('textarea', style=True):
    style = parseStyle(textarea['style'])
    style['width'] = '200px'
    textarea['style'] = style.cssText.replace('\n', ' ')

with open('output.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_html:
    f_html.write(str(soup))
```

So if your HTML is:

```html
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="123" attributeX="4" attributeY="5" style="width:159px; height:50px;"></textarea>
<textarea id="456" attributeX="4" attributeY="5" style="width:135px; height:50px;"></textarea>
<textarea id="789" attributeX="4" attributeY="5" style="width:177px; height:50px;"></textarea>
<textarea id="789" attributeX="4" attributeY="5"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

The output would become:

```html
<html>
<body>
<textarea attributex="4" attributey="5" id="123" style="width: 200px; height: 50px"></textarea>
<textarea attributex="4" attributey="5" id="456" style="width: 200px; height: 50px"></textarea>
<textarea attributex="4" attributey="5" id="789" style="width: 200px; height: 50px"></textarea>
<textarea attributex="4" attributey="5" id="789"></textarea></body>
</html>
```

---

Here the final `<textarea>` is unchanged as there was no style. If required, this could be added as follows:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cssutils import parseStyle

with open('input.html') as f_html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_html, 'html.parser')
    
for textarea in soup.find_all('textarea'):
    if 'style' in textarea.attrs:
        # Update existing style
        style = parseStyle(textarea['style'])
        style['width'] = '200px'
        textarea['style'] = style.cssText.replace('\n', ' ')
    else:
        # Add missing style
        textarea['style'] = 'width: 200px; height: 50px'

with open('output.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_html:
    f_html.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!
Nevertheless, you mentioned it is possible to enforce applying the style if a tag doesn't have the style attribute at all. Can you please tell me, how I can do that?

Comment: No problem, I have added a version that can do that too